When I try rendering JavaScript using HTMLSession it gives me an error
I tried rendering JavaScript using HTMLSession, yet when I tried it gave me an error.
>>> r.html.render()
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.detachFromTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.detachFromTarget: Target closed.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): No session with given id')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): No session with given id

Is there anyway I could fix this issue?
I've tried searching for this issue, yet to no avail.

please add the smallest code that reproduces this problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@folen gateis
from requests_html import HTMLSession r=HTMLSession().get("any website at all") r.html.render()
This code is what gives me an error
